# how to get variable from another class using a doPost

Tags: jsp, servlets

So I am writing a servlet that simply handle my form. The form is actually a registration page, only with additional file input. Therefore, I need to make it as multipart and method post. The servlet is using doPost method to retrieve the information. On the other hand, the servlet also retrieve information from another class in other packages. That class is to read the properties file. I've done my research, browsing the Internet and also the documentation on the official page. Can anyone help me?

servlet code

```
package net.codejava.upload;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import readConfig.readConfig;

@WebServlet("/uploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)    // upload file's size up to   16MB
public class FileUploadDBServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * 
 */



    readConfig readcfg= new readConfig();

// database connection setting

String dbURL = readcfg.getProperties("conUrl");
String dbUser = readConfig.getProperties("dbUser");
String dbPass = readConfig.getProperties("dbUser");


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // gets values of text fields
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String city = request.getParameter("city");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    System.out.println(dbURL);
    System.out.println(dbUser);
    System.out.println(dbPass);

    InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

    // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    if (filePart != null) {
        // prints out some information for debugging
        System.out.println(filePart.getName());
        System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
        System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

        // obtains input stream of the upload file
        inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
    }

    Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
    String message = null;  // message will be sent back to client

    try {
        // connects to the database
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

        // constructs SQL statement
        String sql = "INSERT INTO ssl_user (name, address, password,city,email,file) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, name);
        statement.setString(2, address);
        statement.setString(3, password);
        statement.setString(4, city);
        statement.setString(5, email);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
            statement.setBlob(6, inputStream);
        }

        // sends the statement to the database server
        int row = statement.executeUpdate();
        if (row > 0) {
            message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            // closes the database connection
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // sets the message in request scope
        request.setAttribute("Message", message);

        // forwards to the message page
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

}

The class that read properties

```
package readConfig;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
public class readConfig {
//call this method from jsp
public static String getProperties(String key) throws IOException
{
InputStream inputStream=readConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
Properties myproperties = new Properties();
/////////////load the properties file
myproperties.load(inputStream);

return myproperties.getProperty(key);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should share what you are getting in your error logs so that we can help you better.What I can assume is you must be getting a NullPointerException when you are trying to connect to your db.
1>In your config.properties file you should have set values for your keys as below(This is just an example)

```
dbURL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb 
dbUser=root
dbPass=root
```

2>In your Servlet class,I assume you are setting wrong value in your variable dbPass

Change it from

```
String dbPass = readConfig.getProperties("dbUser");
```

to

```
String dbPass = readConfig.getProperties("dbPass");
```

You are setting username in your password variable

3>This is just a suggestion
Name of the class should begin with capital letter(In your code class readConfig)

Answer (score 0):

so i figured out the error of my code. due to the getProperties class is implement IOException, therefore it cannot be read by default constructor. therefore the solution is simply move the database connection setting inside the doPost class. haha thanks though.

Comment: You should accept your answer to let people know what worked for You.